# How to read and calculate hash of file on the internet

Tags: java, file, stream

I have a url of a file on the Internet. I need to calculate the SHA1 hash, and read this file by each line. I know how to do this, but I read this file twice which probably isn't a very good solution.

How can I do this more effectively?

Here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL(url);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
logger.error(urlConnection.getContent() + " ");
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();


// first reading of file is:

int i;
File file = new File("nameOfFile");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
BufferedOutputStream bos = 
           new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file.getName()));
while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
    bos.write(i);
}
bos.flush();
bis.close();   
sha1(file);

// second reading of file is:

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   // do something
}

protected byte[] sha1(final File file) throws Exception {
    if (file == null || !file.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    final MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA1);

    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    try {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int read = 0; (read = is.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            messageDigest.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
    }
    return messageDigest.digest();
}
```

Comment: Read it in one go, updating the message digest and then writing to the output file. Also, in your first snippet, you're reading and writing one byte at a time, so even though you have buffered streams, you are looping unnecessarily many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass it through a [`DigestInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/DigestInputStream.html), it'll do the `MessageDigest` and still be usable as an `InputStream`.

```
DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is,
  MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA1));
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(dis);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
  new FileOutputStream(file.getName()));
while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
   bos.write(i);
}
bos.close();
return dis.getMessageDigest().digest();
```

Comment: In what way?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: What?  This approach lets you get the digest and copy to the output stream in a single go.  There isn't a solution that will let you reread an input stream in any event.

Comment: The digest/hash is the returned value. It is a byte[] but you can convert it to an hexadecimal String if you need to. @LouisWasserman's solution is fine